# adding jwt authguard throws unauthorized error

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I have written the following `login` module with the `nesjts` 'typeorm'.

```
@Post('login')  
public async login(@Body() data) {            
return await this.authService.login( data);  
}
```

It works fine and send me the desired result (contains the jwt token).

But when I add `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))` at the top of this service, I get the error `401`, `unauthorized access`.

I don't understand why it gives this error, because when I login I will protect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you login, the request doesn't have the `jwt` token in the header.
The login method shouldn't be protected by the guard.